# Space Shuttle OMS maneuvers

Tags: space-shuttle

I'm writing an essay titled the Physics of a Shuttle Mission, which is broken down into the journey into orbit, orbital maneuvering and re-entry.

The biggest problem at the moment is with example calculations. For example the delta v required for OMS-1 and OMS-2. This is because it seems impossible to find info on the Shuttle's velocities and altitudes beyond about T plus 8min. And I believe that OMS-1 occurs at around T plus 10min 30 sec.

Does anyone have any specific numerical data on OMS-1 and OMS-2? Or could point me to a place that has this information.

Comment: You want to know delta V for OMS-1 and -2?  FYI, most flights did not perform OMS-1.

Comment: I understand that most shuttle flights did not perform OMS-1, but surely there has to be some sort of generic data on the velocities and altitudes involved with these maneuvers?

Comment: OK, answered below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Delta-V for most OMS 1 & 2 burns performed during the Space Shuttle program is available in the ever-useful [Space Shuttle Missions Summary](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20110001406/downloads/20110001406.pdf) document in the LAUNCH SITE LIFTOFF TIME column.

For example, here is the data for STS-135. Planned and actual.

[image]

Edit: just noticed you asked about altitude as well.  The altitude at OMS-2 burn isn't explicitly called out in that document, but it does give the orbital altitudes for post OMS-2.  Since OMS-2 was a perigee raising burn, and was performed at apogee, you can use the apogee number for "post OMS 2" as a close approximation.  For STS-135 this was 124.3 nm.

Comment: One question on the units used for Velocity, is FPS feet per second?

Comment: That's correct.